Elasticsearch: Best way to index paths
I am building an index on text files, containing an embedding vector and a file path, amongst other attributes.
I want to run kNN queries on these embeddings and use a directory path for pre-filtering.
e.g., Filtering by /data/folder1 would only consider files under this directory as candidates.
Also, the files may be contained right under folder1 or within subdirectories.
I thought about using prefix or wildcard queries and indexing the file paths as strings but this would be an expensive operation.
What is the most efficient way of achieving this?

You can refer my article about Filesystem Path or Hierarchy on medium which will help you to achieve your requirements.
Elasticsearch provide Path Hierarchy tokenizer which you can use and apply on path field and same can be used for searching as well.
Below is sample index mapping configuration for same:
PUT document
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "path-analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "path-tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "path-tokenizer": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": "/"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "path": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "path-analyzer",
        "fielddata": true
      }
    }
  }
}

